# Displaying the longer name of column in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have table in Access with really long names. For example: **Date of goods entry**. It was obviously too long so I shortened it a little and now it looks like this: **DateofGoodEntr** .

Then I created a splitform based on this table. I want to have real column names displayed, so I want to have "**Date of goods entry**" displayed. I have many columns with even longer names, so I can't just change the caption cause there is not enough space.

So what I want to do is when I hover my mouse on the caption it will display the full name (thorugh for example displaying description or sth else)

Is it possible?

Comment: Use the `ControlTipText` property of the control to display whatever text you want.

Comment: But it doesn't work on columns names on splitform. It works only on "form part" of the splitform, and I want to use it on the column headings in splitform in table.

Comment: If you are using a form/sub-form setup, then this does work.

Comment: @Applecore is there no other way to do this?